# MSO Button Background Color

Tags: html, button, outlook, html-email

I am trying to increase the amount of orange background on this button on MSO email clients. The button works as expected on all other email clients.
Right now the orange fits tightly around the text on MSO when I want it to surround it like the rendered button on the other clients. It does not "fill" like expected.

```html
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;><tr><td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" align="center"><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://mktg.bsqu.com/##purl##/w1_purl.html" style="height:31.5pt;width:198.75pt;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="10%" stroke="false" bgcolor="#e772a2b"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0"><center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px"><!
                          [endif]--><a
                            href="https://mktg.bsqu.com/##purl##/w1_purl.html"
                            style="
                              -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
                              text-decoration: none;
                              display: inline-block;
                              color: #ffffff;
                              background-color: #e77a2b;
                              border-radius: 4px;
                              -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                              -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                              width: auto;
                              width: auto;
                              border-top: 1px solid #e77a2b;
                              border-right: 1px solid #e77a2b;
                              border-bottom: 1px solid #e77a2b;
                              border-left: 1px solid #e77a2b;
                              padding-top: 5px;
                              padding-bottom: 5px;
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica,
                                sans-serif;
                              text-align: center;
                              mso-border-alt: none;
                              word-break: keep-all;
                            "
                            target="_blank"
                            ><span
                              style="
                                padding-left: 20px;
                                padding-right: 20px;
                                font-size: 16px;
                                display: inline-block;
                                letter-spacing: undefined;
                              "
                              ><span
                                style="
                                  font-size: 16px;
                                  line-height: 2;
                                  word-break: break-word;
                                  mso-line-height-alt: 32px;
                                "
                                >Download the Brochure</span
                              ></span
                            ></a
                          >
```

Here is how it renders on Outlook:
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the rest of the button code. Hard to debug without seeing what it actually looks like.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein, yes, adding now - sorry about that!

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein, added rest of button code, more clarification and a screenshot of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm getting an error when trying to use your original code. Outlook isn't liking it at all. There is a service buttons.cm which will help you with button formatting however many in the industry feel that code is outdated and code like the snippet below or [Mark Robbins button code](https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/link-button), is a lot more flexible in all email clients.
I personally use Mark Robbin's code, but it can be quite jarring for those who don't have a lot of experience with html email, so the snippet below will work just fine.

1. Pretty much universally friendly.
2. Still requires Outlook workarounds.
3. The link uses borders to padd the linked area for better support in more clients.
4. Padding values used in the Outlook code, should almost match the border width values. I've personally found 5px left on all sides, mimics the button height and width in Outlook with all other email clients.
5. This method of button coding requires only one update to the URL whereas your old code and the buttons.cm require two URL updates

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#e77a2b" style="padding:9px 15px;" valign="top">
<![endif]-->
<a class="button" href="https://mktg.bsqu.com/##purl##/w1_purl.html" target="_blank" style="background-color:#e77a2b;border-collapse:separate !important;border-top:14px solid #e77a2b;border-right:20px solid #e77a2b;border-bottom:14px solid #e77a2b;border-left:20px solid #e77a2b;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none; border-radius:4px;">Download the Brochure</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

Let me know if you encounter any issues with this.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstien - thank you SO much!! This works great. Implemented, tested and all looks and functions as expected. I really appreciate this.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear :)